# Postpone message excution to specific time using RedisMqHost

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd, redismqserver

Is it possible to use RedisMqServer as simple task scheduler? For example to publish a message and execute it in feature (at specific time)?

Answer (score 0):

[RedisMQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis) doesn't provide any explicit support for delayed messages itself, but you could use simulate it with a Timer, e.g:

```
var sendInMs = 30 * 1000;
new System.Threading.Timer(msg => mqClient.Publish(msg), 
    msg, 
    sendInMs, 
    Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: hmm, there is some risk if code is executed on asp.net and for example application pool is recycled or iis restarted. I was planning publishing (scheduling) message to durable store (redis). I will probably use simpler approach using task scheduler and wget64.exe ... Anyway thanks for answer